# Adding .docx as body to Outlook e-mail in VBA

Tags: vba

I have this code that I can use to send out e-mails with vba in Excel.

Using .body instead of .Inspector.WordEditor I can type exactly what I want to be in the e-mail, but I want the text of the e-mail to be a Word document with some pictures in it and stuff.

How would I go about that? I cannot get .Inspector.WordEditor to work the way that I want it to. (To be honest it does not work at all for me)

```
Sub Test1()

Dim networkstatus As Boolean
If InternetGetConnectedState(0&, 0&) Then
    networkstatus = True
Else
    networkstatus = False
End If
If Not networkstatus = True Then
        Exit Sub
End If

Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim cell As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

On Error GoTo cleanup
For Each cell In Columns("B").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And _
       LCase(Cells(cell.Row, "C").Value) = "yes" Then

        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
        On Error Resume Next
        With OutMail
            .To = cell.Value
            .Subject = "Test"
            .Inspector.WordEditor ("C:\test.docx")
            .Send
        End With
        On Error GoTo 0
        Set OutMail = Nothing
    End If
Next cell
```

cleanup:

```
Set OutApp = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True



End Sub
```

Edit: I am aware that you can use HTMLBody, but I do not count on my colleagues to use that.

Answer (score 0):

Send it as an attachment instead

`.Attachments.Add("C:\test.docx")`

Comment: But I want it to go into the body of the e-mail. It is for a newsletter.

Comment: You are going to need to save it as HTML then, which Word can do. Then read the HTML into the email body. However, keep in mind that most modern email providers disable pictures by default.